# Copying WindowsImageBackup folder

Tags: windows-7, windows-7-backup, windows-7-restore

After making an image backup in Windows 7 Pro 64bit to another partition on the same physical hard drive there is `WindowsImageBackup` folder. After that if I wanted to save this backup to an external drive would copying the `WindowsImageBackup` folder to an external drive be sufficient or is it more involved than that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Copying the *WindowsImageBackup* folder from the partition to another physical drive is sufficient. Make sure you copy the *WindowsImageBackup* folder with elevated privileges (just for sure) - as I'm not sure right now if the folder is protected as system folder or not.

Comment: it does require administrator privileges to access the backup folders

Comment: Notes: the copied folder will not show the same icon and when double-clicking it will not open the backup program. But we can start the backup program and then select "Select another back-up to restore files from". I have copied the folder to the root of the USB drive (not sure, if this is required)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Copy the whole folder with admin access is just fine. If you have other disk imaging tool, for example Disk Genius, you can just copy the .vhd file in fact. The .vhd file is the actual backup.